# Convert 24-Hour Formatted Time Into Decimal Number

Tags: mysql

I want to display `17.5` instead of `17:30:00`. How to achieve this? I've searched but nothing found.

I want to do it inside my query like:

```
SELECT o.*, u.* ,p.* ,
        SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(dateto, '%m/%d/%y %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) - TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(datefrom, '%m/%d/%y %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')))) AS totalHrs,

        number_format((select SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(dateto, '%m/%d/%y %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) - TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(datefrom, '%m/%d/%y %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')))) FROM overtime WHERE approve_by=0)) AS grandTotal

        FROM overtime AS o, users AS u, position AS p
        WHERE o.user_id=u.user_id and u.p_id=p.p_id and o.approve_by=0
        GROUP BY p.p_id
        ORDER BY p.position_name ASC
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a time value, then something like this:

```
select time_to_sec(timeval) / (60 * 60)
```

If you want it to 1 decimal, then convert to a decimal:

```
select cast(time_to_sec(timeval) / (60 * 60) as decimal(10, 1))
```

It is not obvious how this fits into your query, which seems a non-sequitur.

Comment: First code works like a charm! Thanks! But how to convert it to 1 Decimal by not using a `CAST`?

Comment: And when the value is `4.0000` it should be a whole number `4`