# Virtual column in phpmyadmin to calculate hours worked

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

EDIT: Answered with help from @fubar

```
TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_SUB(TIMEDIFF(finish_time, start_time), INTERVAL break MINUTE)) / 3600
```

---

I have a table with:
start_time as time
finish_time as time
break as int (number of minutes the employee went on break)
total_hours as decimal, which should be the number of hours the employee worked for. So if start_time is 5:00, finish_time is 13:00, and break is 30, total_hours should be 7.5
In phpMyAdmin, with the total_hours column set to VIRTUAL, what expression should I put in? I tried

```
TIMEDIFF(finish_time, start_time)
```

to begin with, which gave me 70000.00 (with parameters 12:00:00 , 5:00:00), which made me realise I had no idea what I was doing and I should just ask someone.

Comment: When I run `SELECT TIMEDIFF('12:00', '5:00');`, I get `07:00:00`. How are you getting `70000.00`? Are you casting or manipulating the result somehow?

Comment: Sorry it was 05:00:00 and 12:00:00, so the 70000.00 is probably a time value of 7:00:00. The field data type is decimal(26,2) if that helps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert 24-Hour Formatted Time Into Decimal Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34346375/convert-24-hour-formatted-time-into-decimal-number)

Comment: That's exactly what I was doing, the field type was Decimal. I've changed it to Time, but I still need the expression in phpmyadmin under virtuality to subtract the break minutes from the time I get from TIMEDIFF().

DATEADD(minutes, -break, (TIMEDIFF(finish_time, start_time))) gives me an error "Function or expression is not allowed for column total_hours"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `SELECT` will get you the total hours worked.

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_SUB(TIMEDIFF(`finish_time`, `start_time`), INTERVAL `break` MINUTE)) / 3600 AS total_hours;
```

To break it down into it's component parts:

Find the time difference between the start and end times.

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('12:00:00', '05:00:00')
```

Subtract the break interval in minutes.

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(TIMEDIFF('12:00:00', '05:00:00'), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE);
```

Convert the time difference to seconds.

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_SUB(TIMEDIFF('12:00:00', '05:00:00'), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE));
```

Convert the time difference in seconds to hours by dividing by 60 * 60.

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_SUB(TIMEDIFF('12:00:00', '05:00:00'), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)) / 3600 AS total_hours;
```

Comment: Great done thanks! Put it in as TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_SUB(TIMEDIFF(finish_time, start_time), INTERVAL break MINUTE)) / 3600 for the Virtuality Expression and it worked